# cedet parsing issue on #ifdef

Tags: emacs, cedet

I 'm emacs cedet user. i got great help from cedet.

but, I found some error prcessing #ifdef handling in cedet.
not sure it's from cedet internal or my mis-configuration.
I quote some code in Curl where this issue happens.

```
#ifdef CURL_DO_LINEEND_CONV
  if((data->set.crlf) || (data->set.prefer_ascii)) {
#else
  if(data->set.crlf) {
#endif /* CURL_DO_LINEEND_CONV */
    endofline_native  = "\n";
```

With this code, there must be some mis-parenthesis match. Because I got errors using (eassist-list-methods) or other cedet-semantic functions (jump to definition).

I could easily guess this might be from two braces in #ifdef .. #endif block.
I contracted these to like this.

```
#ifdef CURL_DO_LINEEND_CONV
  if((data->set.crlf) || (data->set.prefer_ascii)) 
#else
  if(data->set.crlf) 
#endif /* CURL_DO_LINEEND_CONV */
{
    endofline_native  = "\n";
```

after this, cedet semantic functions works well.

any idea about this? is it from cedet parser problem?

if there is some point I have to configure in cedet, could you give me some insight ?

thanks

Comment: Please consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. The Emacs developers will determine whether or not there is a problem.

Comment: Please, also report issue to cedet-devel mailing list

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, but in case anyone is still struggling with this, add the following line to to your emacs init file:

```
(setq semantic-c-obey-conditional-section-parsing-flag nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a problem that setting `semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file`
could solve.
According to what I've read about CEDET, it doesn't just expand every macro
willy nilly, but only those defined in `semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file`.
So you should add the file, where `CURL_DO_LINEEND_CONV` is defined to this list.
Here's an example:

```
(add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file
             "~/Software/deal.II/include/deal.II/base/config.h")
```

Hope this helps.